# Keep xmlns location while running XSL processor on XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, msxsl

I want to add a node to an XML document using xslt. I am using msxsl as processor. The XML document has this structure:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PlatformShortName>SDK_NAME</PlatformShortName>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The XSL rule inserts the desired node:

(**Edit**: added the XSL namespace)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
exclude-result-prefixes="ms">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="ms:Project/ms:PropertyGroup">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <xsl:element name="PlatformInstructionSet">AMRv7</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </PropertyGroup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But the result has moved the namespace attribute from `Project` to `PropertyGroup`.

(**Edit**: I want the `Project` and the `PropertyGroup` identical to the input.)

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PlatformInstructionSet>AMRv7</PlatformInstructionSet>
        <PlatformShortName>SDK_NAME</PlatformShortName>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It's necessary to avoid it. How can I only add an node without changing the structure? Additionall I would like to have the new node inserted like the other nodes.

Comment: You're not showing an important part of your stylesheet: the namespace declarations in the header. And it's not clear what the output should be.

Comment: The result you show is not the result received: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5V

Comment: That's because he added this `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
exclude-result-prefixes="ms"`. If it will be removed,  the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your expected output is.

If you want to keep the original namespace and insert the new element into it, then do:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
exclude-result-prefixes="ms">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ms:PropertyGroup">
    <xsl:copy>
        <PlatformInstructionSet>AMRv7</PlatformInstructionSet>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want to remove the namespace altogether, then do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
exclude-result-prefixes="ms">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ms:PropertyGroup">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PlatformInstructionSet>AMRv7</PlatformInstructionSet>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </PropertyGroup>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the input you have provided, the templates can be rewritten as following:

```
<xsl:template match="ms:Project/ms:PropertyGroup">
    <PropertyGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <xsl:element name="PlatformInstructionSet">AMRv7</xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </PropertyGroup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note:**

Adding `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"` in `<PropertyGroup>` would consider it's child to be in the same namespace as the parent and hence it won't add it in child node.

Also it will add `xmlns=""` in `<PropertyGroup>` if the namespace is not added to this node. (specifically for this case with given template)